# Case Insensitive regular expression in the condition

Tags: apigee

I have the following condition

```
 <Condition>request.header.User-Agent ~~ "id1" or request.header.User-Agent ~~ "id2"</Condition>
```

Is it possible to configure it to make the regular expression matching to carry out in the case insensitive mode?

Answer (score 0):

`~~` is a java.util.regex match. From the [Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE), you can use `(?i)` to force a case-insensitive match.

```
<Condition>request.header.User-Agent ~~ "(?i)id1" or request.header.User-Agent ~~ "(?i)id2"</Condition>
```